# How to test for OAuth object?

Tags: php, oop, object, oauth

I have a function that accepts an [OAuth object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php):

```
$oauth = new OAuth("abc","def",OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);

function get_oauth_header($oauth, $header)
{
    if ( !is_string($header) ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    $result_headers = explode("\r\n", $oauth->getLastResponseHeaders());
    // Do something interesting....
}
```

I would like to add a check at the top of the function to ensure that only valid OAuth objects are passed to the function, as is done with the `$header` variable being checked that it is a string. **How might I check this?** I have tried to output the type of an OAuth object with `gettype()` but it returns `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP5 introduced a feature that will help you here: [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). You can use it to require certain parameters to be instances of a certain class.

```
function get_oauth_header(OAuth $oauth, $header) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that this will produce a fatal error if the $oauth passed is not an instance of `OAuth`.

As an alternative, you were sort-of on the right track with `gettype()`, but this will only report PHP's internal type. What you needed here was `instanceof` or [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php).

```
var_dump($oauth instanceof OAuth); // true
var_dump(get_class($oauth) === 'OAuth'); // true
```

Comment: Thank you for a full, informative answer that attacks the question and the problem at hand. Great answer!